# Showing name in drop down select box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I want to create a task and assign to a particular user who has_one profile with first name and last name.

And also user has_many tasks.

My new task form is

```
 <%= form_for :task do |f| %> 

    <div>
    <%= f.label :task %>
    <%= f.text_area :task %>
    </div> 

    <div>
    <%= f.label :assigned_to %>
    <%= f.collection_select(:assigned_to, User.profile.all, :fist_name, :fist_name, :include_blank => 'None')%>
    </div>
```

in the collection select I should display something like " Sam Parker (sam@org.com)" like this all the users should be available in the collection select field.

Can anyone help me how to display it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the rails guides it provides good information on the subject.Here is the link:  http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#making-select-boxes-with-ease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all read the documentation here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-collection_select

I guess you need to create a method that returns the option's text, for example:

```
class User < ActiveRecordBase
  # ...
  def label_for_select
    "#{profile.full_name} (#{profile.email})"
  end
end
```

Then, in your view it would be something like:

```
<div>
  <%= f.label :assigned_to_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:assigned_to_id, User.all, :id, :label_for_select, :include_blank => 'None')%>
</div>
```

Notice that the form sets the `assigned_to_id` not the `assign_to` ruby object. Rails will instantiate the `assign_to` object based on this id.